# ¿Cómo saber qué conexiones tengo activas como hace Netstat?

Tags: android, socket

Necesito saber cómo averiguar que conexiones tengo establecidas, algo similar a lo que hace netstat.

[image: listado ejemplo]

Sólo tengo que obtener el listado en un array o en un list para comprobar que la que me interesa quede abierta, pero no se ni por donde empezar. Alguna idea?
Gracias

Comment: Podrías usar el comando `NetStat`,que esenciamente lo que hace es leer lo que hay en `/proc/net/tcp`.[Aqui tienes ejemplos de uso](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.os.NetStat)

Comment: Le echo un ojo y te comento, gracias

Comment: A raíz d elo que me has pùesto he conseguido llegar a la respuesta que me ha funcionado, muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada. Me alegro que te haya servido

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con esto lo he solucionado

```
try {
        // Run the command
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        // Grab the results
        StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        int numLineas = 0;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line + "\n");
            numLineas++;
        }

        String[] lineas = new String[numLineas];
        lineas = log.toString().split("\\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

Obtenemos las conexiones activas (con mas información) en un array de String

Comment: gran aporte, no sabia que se pudiera obtener esos datos